# Typescript project hitting wrong debug point (visual studio 2015 cordova project)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 RTM and making a hybrid app ,but it seems the typescript debugger is always hitting the wrong point (sometimes not even a break point), it arbitrary hit anywhere in any file in the project, below is the screen shot [image: visual studio debugger hit]

Please help me with the issue

Comment: Alternatively you can set breakpoints in the browser and just forget about VS. I'm not diving into TypeScript (and any other source to js compiler) for these kind of issues :(

Comment: thanx for reply , at present i am doing that only but there are some cordova related things which are only visible when i debug in vs

Comment: Can you use developer tools in cordova to check if the map file maps the line correctly there?

Comment: HI, I encountered the same problem. The execution point in the "call stack" window is CORRECT but the code window shows WRONG line.

Comment: @smartkid did you find any solution ??

Comment: @PranayDutta  not for now ......   I think the issue is about "Call Stack" rather than "Breakpoints". When I double click in the "Call Stack" window, VS highlights incorrect source file/line. I am still fighting ....

Comment: @PranayDutta Just a workaround:  Disable the source map when generating "appBundle.js" and set breakpoint in `appBundle.js` rather than in `*.ts`

Comment: @PranayDutta I put a tsconfig.json with line `"sourceMap": false` 
 in the `scripts` folder which all `ts` files live in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been resolved in tools for apache cordova update 2

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the debugger work !

I removed all `/// <references path=""` lines at the top of all `.ts` files.

The downside is, modules can NOT use `import` for other internal modules because the imported module variable may (or may not) be initialized after the importing module in `appBundle.js`.

Comment: but i am keeping a compilation sequence in index.ts and for that i need to give the references in which it needs to compile

Comment: when i am running in windows 10 emulator,works like a charm,seems that android and ios are breaking it apart